# C++ if-else if Issues

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm having issues with my program below. It should convert numbers between 1-100 to AA,BA,BB,CB,CC,D,F. But it stops working and shows "BA" if I enter number less than 84. I checked the code. But I don't understand what is the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int secenek,notu;
    cout << "Not Dönüştürücü" << endl;
    cout<<"Başlamak için 1'e basın:\n";
    cin>>secenek;

    if (secenek==1)
        {
        cout<<"Dönüştürülecek not: ";
        cin>>notu;
        }
        if (notu<0 || notu>100)
            {
            cout<<"Geçerli bir not girin.\n";
            }
        else if (notu>=90)
            {
            cout<<"AA";
            }
        else if (notu<90 || notu>84)
            {
            cout<<"BA";
            }
        else if (notu<85 || notu>79)
            {
            cout<<"BB";
            }
        else if (notu<80 || notu>74)
            {
            cout<<"CB";
            }
        else if (notu<75 || notu>69)
            {
            cout<<"CC";
            }
        else if (notu<70 || notu>59)
            {
            cout<<"D";
            }
        else if (notu<60)
            {
            cout<<"F";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You confound `||` (or) and `&&` (and) in most of your tests.

Comment: `(notu<90 || notu>84)` will always be true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you made a logical error:

```
else if (notu<90 || notu>84)
```

should be

```
else if (notu<90 && notu>84)
```

and the same goes for all the following conditions.

**EDIT** as @Jarod42 suggested; you don't even need to check `notu<90` anymore... your code could look like this:

```
if (notu<0 || notu>100)
    {
    cout<<"Geçerli bir not girin.\n";
    }
else if (notu>=90)
    {
    cout<<"AA";
    }
else if (notu>84)
    {
    cout<<"BA";
    }
else if (notu>79)
    {
    cout<<"BB";
    }
etc...
```

Comment: As remark: `notu < 90` is even useless as it is already checked by previous test.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition

```
else if (notu<90 || notu>84)
```

will always be true, whatever notu is set to. You probably mean

```
else if (notu < 90 && notu > 84)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part:

```
    else if (notu<90 || notu>84)
        {
        cout<<"BA";
        }
    else if (notu<85 || notu>79)
        {
        cout<<"BB";
        }
    else if (notu<80 || notu>74)
        {
        cout<<"CB";
        }
```

`else if (notu<90 || notu> 84)` will trigger on any `notu` lower than 90 and on any `notu` higher than 84. That's all pretty much all who survived the earlier check.

Correct implementation would be `else if (notu<90 && notu> 84)` which will only trigger if both conditions are met.

My C++ is a bit rusty, but if I remember correctly one could even write `else if (84 < notu < 90)`.
EDIT:  `else if (84 < notu < 90)` isn't valid C++ syntax.

Comment: C++ doesn't support the short way `if (84 < notu < 90)` as python does.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I got indeed confused with Python.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using `||` where `&&` would be logically correct.

But you don't really need `&&` either - you can simplify a bit since in the `else` branch you already know that the corresponding `if` condition is false.

Like this:

```
if (notu < 0 || notu > 100)
{
    cout << "Geçerli bir not girin.\n";
}
else if (notu >= 90)
{
    cout << "AA";
}
else if (notu >= 85) // Already know that it's < 90, because it's not >= 90
{
    cout << "BA";
}

// ...
// ...

else if (notu >= 60) // Already know that it's < 70
{
    cout << "D";
}
else   // Already know that it's < 60
{
    cout << "F";
}
```